# How to style curreny decimal in mat input field

Tags: angular, css, angular-material

how to bring below look and feel in angular 4 using mat input field.
while enter the number it should be normal. while focus out decimal value should be look power value. is any tricks achieve for this.

i tried in material chip component but is not working

**sample UI**

[image]

Comment: make a plunker with an example code and we can resolve it